# Save tabs as new worksheets & rename the tab in the new files

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that saves each tab in a workbook as a new file.

```
Dim xPath As String
xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each xWs In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    xWs.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

After saving the new file, I need to rename the tab within "Product" in every case as this is a requirement for importing the file to another program.  Is this possible without opening every new file individually?

Comment: `xWs.Name = "Product"` after the `xws.copy`?

Comment: have you tried, when looping, renaming the activesheet, then use .move to put it into a new workbook?  as you move each sheet out of the workbook, you shouldn't see any error with multiple sheets("product")

Comment: @ScottCraner “That name is already taken. Try a different one.”  It looks like the right line, but is it possible to put it somewhere else?

Comment: `Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name = "Product"` instead.

Comment: @ScottCraner I need the file to be named after the original tab name, then rename the tab within the new file "Product".  So, the renaming of the tab can't happen until after the save.  Right?

Comment: that is why I changed the reference  after `xws.copy` put the line above and do not use the first one I recommended.

Comment: if that does not work then put the name of the sheet in a variable before changing the name and use the variable in the save.

Comment: @ScottCraner The Application solution fixed it.  Pretty sure you've earned my paycheck from this week as this is the third question of mine you've answered.  Thank you so much for every suggestion.